# Read QR code with BoofCV JAR in command line Windows

Tags: java, image-processing, qr-code, boofcv

I used Zxing library for reading QR codes, however, the failure ratio to read QR codes is quite high and was looking for alternatives.

BoofCV looks good according to tests: https://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Performance:QrCode

However, I'm struggling to make it work and find any tutorials in Windows command line using JAR files.

I have the latest 0.33.1 release libraries (https://sourceforge.net/projects/boofcv/files/v0.33.1/):
[image]

Is there any simple way to run from command line, I was expecting something like:

```
java -jar boofcv-recognition-0.33.1.jar -inputQRCodeImagePath [path to local image with QR code]
```

And then in command line to get text output of what was encoded in QR code, which I can process further.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: BoofCV is missing an easy to use command line QR Code scanning application. That will be fixed in the future. For now you can [Download](https://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Applications) Example and Demonstrations application run a GUI application to test it out. I'll add an answer once this has been fixed.

Comment: @lessthanoptimal thanks for feedback. I donwnloaded the examples, but it was just detecting the location of QR in hardcoded image, what I'm looking is giving custom image as input and get text from QR as output. When you say there is no easy command line interface, but in general this is doable with custom JAVA development, right?

Comment: correct, you can write your own command line java application. In the future there will hopefully be one you can download.

Answer (score 1):

This feature has was added a few months ago. Download the [BoofApplications](https://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Applications), then follow the steps below:

1. unzip BoofApplications.zip
2. cd BoofApplications
3. `java -jar applications.jar BatchScanQrCodes`

That will print out help. To scan for QR codes in all directories in a path do the following:

```
java -jar applications.jar BatchScanQrCodes --Recursive -i path/to/input -o path/to/output
```

Every 50 files it will print out the number of files scanned. Took less than a minute to scan the entire test set of QR codes 562 images. You will then have a file which looks like:

```
# Found QR Codes inside of images
# ../ValidationBoof/data/fiducials/qrcodes
# Format:
# <File Name> <Total Found>
# message encoded with URLEncoder 
1 ../ValidationBoof/data/fiducials/qrcodes/decoding/v3SMS-Text.png SMSTO%3A555-123-5555%3AMessage+to+Be+Sent.
1 ../ValidationBoof/data/fiducials/qrcodes/decoding/v2SMS-Text.png SMS%3A555-123-5555
1 ../ValidationBoof/data/fiducials/qrcodes/decoding/v2Location.png geo%3A32.81361685253009%2C-117.15371310710907 
1 ../ValidationBoof/data/fiducials/qrcodes/decoding/v3VCard-BasicWikipedia.png BEGIN%3AVCARD%0D%0AVERSION%3A3.0%0D%0AN%3AGump%3BForrest%0D%0AFN%3AForrest+Gump12.01%0D%0AORG%3ABubba+Gump+Shrimp+Co.%0D%0ATITLE%3AShrimp+Man%0D%0APHOTO%3BVALUE%3DURL%3BTYPE%3DPNG%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.printbusinesscards.com%2Fw%2Fimages%2Fclassic%2Fpbc_header_logo.png%0D%0ATEL%3BTYPE%3DWORK%2CVOICE%3A%28111%29+555-1212%0D%0ATEL%3BTYPE%3DHOME%2CVOICE%3A%28404%29+555-1212%0D%0AADR%3BTYPE%3DWORK%3A%3B%3B100+Waters+Edge%3BBaytown%3BLA%3B30314%3BUnited+States+of+America%0D%0ALABEL%3BTYPE%3DWORK%3A100+Waters+Edge%5CnBaytown%2C+LA+30314%5CnUnited+States+of+America%0D%0AADR%3BTYPE%3DHOME%3A%3B%3B42+Plantation+St.%3BBaytown%3BLA%3B30314%3BUnited+States+of+America%0D%0ALABEL%3BTYPE%3DHOME%3A42+Plantation+St.%5CnBaytown%2C+LA+30314%5CnUnited+States+of+America%0D%0AEMAIL%3BTYPE%3DPREF%2CINTERNET%3Aforrestgump%40example.com%0D%0AREV%3A20080424T195243Z%0D%0AEND%3AVCARD%0D%0A
```